# VUE 3 TS 2339 : The property xxx doesn't exist ont type {

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I use : Vue3 with TS, axios, sequelize.

I'm creating a form with just 1 textarea, to post a post on a wall, and I wrote that script in my component form :

```html
<template>
  <div id="PostText" class="col-12">
    <form id="postTextForm">
      <div id="PostwriteContent">
        <label for="PostContent">
          <h2>Lâchez nous vos pensées...</h2>
        </label>
        <textarea
          name="PostContent"
          id="PostContent"
          cols="65"
          rows="6"
          v-model="theNewPost.content"
          autocapitalize="sentence"
          form="postTextForm"
          maxlength="650"
          placeholder="Saisissez ici votre prose..."
          required
          autofocus
        ></textarea>
        <button class="col-9" type="button" :disabled="!isFormValid" @click="sendMyPost">Poster</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
    errorMessage: String,
      theNewPost: {
        content: String,
        userId: Number 
      }
    };
  },
  methods: {
    sendMyPost(e:any){
      e.preventDefault();
      
      console.log("testPost >>" + this.theNewPost.content);
      console.log("theNewPost >>" + this.theNewPost);

      axios.post("http://localhost:3001/api/feed", this.theNewPost)
        .then((res) =>{ 
          console.log('Post en ligne ;)' + res)
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          this.errorMessage = err.message;
          console.error("There was an error!", err);
        })

    }
  },
  computed:{
    isFormValid(){
      if (
        this.theNewPost.content !== ""
      ) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
  },

};

</script>
```

But I have some errors where I use "this." it doesn't found the name theNewPost , errorMessage,
So I don't understand the point cause I defined those terms in data and I use them in V-model.

Moreover in my form where I bind my 2 functions, they doesn't run . Do you know which mistakes I did. Please.

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To [enable TypeScript support](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/typescript-support.html#defining-vue-components), wrap the component with `defineComponent()`:

```js
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
  data() { ... },
  methods: { ... },
  computed: { ... },
})
```

Also note your `data()` return should be literals (not initialized to `String` or `Number`):

```js
data() {
  return {
    errorMessage: '',
    theNewPost: {
      content: '',
      userId: 0
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: It saved me! Despite I have a good knowledge level of Vue 2, currently I'm still learning the key points of the third version. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue.
While all the files where working just fine,
there was a problem this ONE file that was throwing an error...

I'm using "ionic serve" to deploy locally and I removed 'lang=ts' from the script tag and re added it.

When it recompiled everything, there was no longer an error :(

There must be an issue with caching... I had similar issues before...

Answer (score 1):

For those who are using Composition API, make sure you have included `setup` in the `script` tag.

### Example

From this

```html
<template>
<div v-for="i in foo">{{i}}</div>
            ^^^^^^^^TS 2339
<template>

<script lang="ts">
const foo=[1,2,3]
</script>
```

To this:

```html
<template>
<div v-for="i in foo">{{i}}</div>
            ^^^^^^^^TS 2339
<template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
                  ^^^^^<-put here
const foo=[1,2,3]
</script>
```